# Simple way to modify GeoWebCache Capabilities?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, wmts

I have been working with `WMTS OGC Standard` in Geoserver and now i'm worried about the metadata of my service. The capabilities document is managed by `GeoWebCache` :

```
http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS&version=1.3.0
```

and there's no visible way to modify some elements such as title, abstract, keywords,... in Geoserver.

I try to find some info by looking for through the internet but no luck. **Is there a way to modify the capabilities generated by gwc?**

Comment: Specifically why you need this?

Comment: I want that some user interested in my WMTS to have particular metadata of the service (title, abstract, keywords), not the one automatically created by geowebcache, when reading the capabilities document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the `WMTS` tab in the left hand menu of the main GeoServer page there is a page that allows you to set any of the Metadata that you want.

[image]

Comment: Nice! What version of Geoserver is bringing this feature? The version I used when asked this question didn't have this option. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not sure when it was added - a while ago, certainly before 2.9 & 2.10